# Thickness / size / volume of a macrophage

Tags: cell-biology

What is the thickness of a macrophage? From some available literature it looks like a macrophage has a 'circular' shape of radius ~10 microns. But I need the thickness to calculate its volume.

Comment: volume is a function of r?

Answer (score 1):

BioNumbers is a good database for different values (numbers) in biological systems. From BioNumbers*:

Volume of an alveolar macrophage ( *Homo sapiens* ) = 4990 (±174) µm<sup>3</sup>

Diameter of an alveolar macrophage ( *Homo sapiens* ) = 21.2 (±0.3)  µm

So, your thickness should be (assuming a circular shape of the cell):

Volume/(pi×(0.5×diameter)<sup>2</sup>) = 14.15 (±1.52) µm

Apparently, the size of the alveolar macrophages varies a lot between different species.

> The AM from humans were significantly larger (p < 0.05) than those
>   from all other species studied, corresponding to a 4-fold larger cell
>   volume of human AM (4990 +/- 174 microns 3) compared to hamster (1328
>   +/- 123 microns 3) and rat (1166 +/- 42 microns 3) AM

---

*
<sub>The paper that BioNumber refers to is this: 
 

Krombach, Fritz, et al. "[Cell size of alveolar macrophages: an interspecies comparison](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9400735)." *Environmental health perspectives* 105.Suppl 5 (1997): 1261.</sub>